# android - Place UI on the edge of another UI

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

[image]

Hi,

I need to create a UI such that an image view appears at the edge of an alert dialog. Please find below the steps in detail.

1. I click on a button in activity.
2. Alert dialog windows should slide from the right to the center.
3. In the edge of the dialog window, i have an image.

I am done till step 2. I don't know how to place an UI such that half of that appears on the dialog view. Please refer to the image i have provided.

Please provide me with the code samples or pointers for implementing the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [frame layout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html)

Answer (score 0):

A dialog is usually a small window that appears in front of the current Activity. The underlying Activity loses focus and the dialog accepts all user interaction.

So, I doubt if such an effect can be obtained in a dialog.

However, I tried using absolute layout as dialog's content view to create a custom dialog and moved the imageview to an edge by altering the layout parameter. That showed only the portion of the imageview that could fit into the dialog and the rest was not visible.

[image: My custom dialog]

Comment: I too tried this but i want the complete image to be visible. Thanks anyways.